# Google Script - Appending google spreadsheet in async mode

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, async-await, spreadsheet

I created a function to append an array to a google spreadsheet. Usually, my array has more than 5 items. In the client side, I group the data in a array and I send to the server using the "google.script.run.*myFunction(params)*". Then, I use a loop structure to do this in the server side. I belive my client side is running even the server side doesn't ended the job.
How I could to do to the client side waits the server side to finish the run?

At least, my server side also running an append to the spreadsheet without to wait the run finish.

**My function in the client side:**

```
function sendArr(){
          var userInfo = {};
          var arr = new Array();
          var localTable = "";
          var gravar = 0;

          try{

            localTable = document.getElementById("scheduleTable");

            if(document.getElementById("repNome").value === "") {
              throw new Error();
            }

            if(document.getElementById("yearSchedule").value === ""){
              throw new Error();
            }; 

            for(var i=1;i<localTable.rows.length;i++){

              for(var y=1;y<localTable.rows[0].cells.length;y++){

                var hour = document.getElementById(localTable.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML+localTable.rows[0].cells[y].innerHTML).value;

                if(hour !== ""){
                  userInfo.repName = document.getElementById("repNome").value;
                  userInfo.week = document.getElementById("yearSchedule").value;
                  userInfo.cdlName = localTable.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
                  userInfo.dayName = localTable.rows[0].cells[y].innerHTML;
                  userInfo.hour = hour; 



                  arr.push(userInfo);

                  gravar = 1;

                }
              }           
            }

            if(gravar === 1) {
              google.script.run.myFunction(arr);
              alert("Ok!")
            };

          } catch(err) {
            alert(err.message);
          }

        }
```

**My function in the server side:**

````
var url = "mylink.com";

function myFunction(arr) {
try{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("AgendaSemanal");
    let userInfo = [];

    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {

      userInfo = arr[i];

      ws.appendRow([userInfo.repName, 
                    userInfo.week, 
                    userInfo.cdlName, 
                    userInfo.dayName, 
                    userInfo.hour,
                    new Date()])

  }               

  } catch(err){
      Logger.log(err);
  } finally {

  return ;
  }
}```
````

Comment: Could you provide a running example of this? Also, have you tried using [withSuccessHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction) as @amitagarwal suggested ? I think it should work fine with this, let me know if it did.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `withSuccessHandler` as shown below:

```
if(gravar === 1) {
  google.script.withSuccessHandler(function() {
    alert("Ok!");
  }).run.myFunction(arr);              
};
```

The callback is called after the server-side returns.

Comment: You can use the `insertRows` method to insert all the data at once instead of doing it one by one using the `appendRow` method.